# ImportError: No module named sip

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, import

I have been trying to write a custom application to generate contour from QGIS.
This is my starting code:

```
import os;
from qgis.core import *;
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Python\test\script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *;
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sip
ImportError: No module named sip
```

Now, i'm stuck here. Don't know what to do.

Comment: You could consider installing QGIS via the [OSGeo4W Network Installer](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) as this contains more python libraries including one which contains the `sip` module. You should then be able to do a simple `import sip`.

Comment: actually sip folder is there in ..\QGIS Wien\apps\python27, but its still giving the error